# Android Boot Service Doesn't Work

Tags: android

My phone is HTC G18 and I'm working with the boot receiver.
The Android Manifest file is:

```
<receiver android:name=".BootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and the Java code is

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    context.startService(new Intent(context, UpdaterService.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES));
    Log.d("BootReceiver", "onReceived");
    Toast.makeText(context, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

When I use this command, the boot receiver will work on my phone.

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -c android.intent.category.HOME
```

But when I try to reboot to test, it will fail. I want this boot receiver will boot with the phone, how can I deal with this?

Comment: Does your application have any `Activity`s? Have you started the application by starting an `Activity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
```

Also you might want to try adding your full package instead of the shorthand .BootReceiver. Such as:

```
com.yourpackage.receivers.BootReceiver
```

EDIT 
Ah, and as mentioned in the comments. You MUST start the main activity of your application at least once otherwise Android will not call your boot receiver.

Comment: I add the package name and it helps. Thank you tencent.